# getResource("/some.jar") returns null, although "some.jar" exists in getURLs()

Tags: java, url, classpath, classloader, getresource

After hours I am giving up on debugging the following:

This works:

```
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs();
    URL myURL = null;
    for (URL url : urls) {
        if (url.getPath().endsWith("some.jar")) {
            myURL = url;
    }   
}
System.out.println(myURL);
```

returns

```
file:/C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository/path/to/some.jar
```

However, all of the following returns `null`:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getResource("/some.jar");
MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getResource("some.jar");
MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getResource("/C:/Users/Me/.m2/repository/path/to/some.jar");
MyClass.class.getClassLoader()).getResource("/path/to/some.jar");
```

As you can see, I would like to get a jar of the user's maven repository by not adressing it absolutely, if possible. The jar is in the classpath, as shown by `getURLs()`
But how the heck do I have to address it in `getResource()` in order to get it?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLClassLoader.getURLs()` returns the URLs to directories and JARs that are in the classpath.  `ClassLoader.getResource(String)` is looking for the resource *inside* the classpath. So unless one of your JARs/directories in the classpath contains `some.jar`, this is expected to fail.

Put another way, if `some.jar` contains `pkg/thingy.png`, then `getResource("pkg/thingy.png")` would succeed.

Also note that `getResource(String)` returns a URL to the resource... a URL that you already have in `myURL`.

Comment: OMG, I think, that's it, thanks! So using getResource() was totally wrong? Is finding the URL with getURLs(), like I did, the preferred way?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. If you are trying to access a resource from *inside* one of the JARs in the classpath, then use `getResource(...)`. If you are trying to get alternate access to the JARs that comprise the classpath -- for example, to do an exhaustive scan of all available images -- use `getURLs(...)`. In my experience, only debugging code and framework code needs to resort to `getURLs`.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I only need that code during development. I expect all developers to have the jar file in their maven repository, which is in classpath. However, for the release I have to place it somewhere else (probably inside the release jar file). Thanks again for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want:

```
MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/to/some.jar")
```

Note the lack of leading slash. That's assuming the "root" of your classloader is effectively `repository`. It's hard to tell just from the URL.

An alternative would be to use:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("/path/to/some.jar")
```

Note that this time there *is* a leading slash. Basically classloaders don't have any concept of a "relative" name, whereas classes do.

Comment: Unfortunately, both also do not work. But due to what Dilum Ranatunga pointed out in his answer, I will probably never be able to find it with getResource(). ;-) But thanks for your answer!